# Firefox places relatively positioned image inside absolutely positioned wrapper inside height-unspecified parent way to the left

Tags: css

I'd like a semi-transparent image fade, over an image element. The image's height should be set by a root element, who's height is in turn set by a different child.

Example html ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpcea/nuzr7w3o/36/)):

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="title">Dynamic title realistic width</div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="fade"></div>

    <!-- Assume that we must use an image component -->
    <img class="image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cea/image/upload/v1692989059/mirroredImages/FWmnwCcKiBLstFtYL/u7hzne1c0znv6hlujrot.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

The title is setting the height. The image should then match the height, and set its width based on its aspect ratio. The fade should then set its width based on the width of the image.

I can basically get what I want in Chrome and Safari, using this CSS:

```css
.root {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* Provides the width for the fade */
.image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* Width is unspecified. Because it's absolutey positioned, it will be the width of the image */
  
  /* stacking context */
  z-index: 0;
}

.fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* This would be white, but we're keeping it grey so we can see the left edge */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.5) 70%, rgba(230, 230, 230, 0) 100%);
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}
```

However in Firefox, it flies off the end of the left hand side.

I've made another, slightly simplified jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpcea/e4y65Lf0/31/), where you can see the image on the left.

It's definitely not a Firefox bug... right? I'm in the market for solutions that meet my constraints, answers that explain why the Firefox behavior is the way it is, or confirmation that there's no way to do what I want to do based on the different browser behaviors here.

Things that I've tried that do not meet my goals:

1. Using a background image. My [codebase](https://github.com/ForumMagnum/ForumMagnum/blob/1e533697d7728fc133049a46d5489781efb5300d/packages/lesswrong/components/spotlights/SpotlightItem.tsx#L330) has an image component that handles srcset, dark mode, and a bunch of other crap for me. I'd like to use that image component. I'd like to do minimal surgery on this Open Source codebase.
2. Specifying a height and width for my image. My image is user-generated, and can have varying aspect ratios.
3. If I relax the constraint that the image fade has to match the size of the image, I can solve the problem, but it looks worse.

Comment: Firefox calculates the width of the image for the purposes of establishing the width of its containing element by using the image's natural width, not its width after being scaled in accordance with its final height, because the height refers back to the percentage of an indefinite height. I don't know anyway of avoiding that,